# bootstrap cards in col not takiing the height of the row in safari

Tags: css, angular, row, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap / angular project. In every browser the cards have the height of the row / col. i have even set it to 100%, but in safari it is not working correctly. In firefox, chrome and edge its fine.

Can sombody help me?

**Code**

parent:

*home-page.html*

```html
<div class="position-relative padding-top-2rem card-container">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- title -->
    <h4 class="text-align-center boldLucas">
      {{'product-page.title.useTheMostInnovativeOSWithNetworkConnectivity' | translate}}
    </h4>
    <!-- cards -->
    <div class="row row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-xl-{{cardElements.length}} g-3 py-5">
      <app-card-content *ngFor="let cardElement of cardElements" [cardElement]="cardElement"></app-card-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*home-page.css*

```css
.card-container {
  background-color: #0A0D2F !important;
}
```

child:

*card-component.html*

```html
<div class="col card-box-schaddow" id="card-box-schaddow-{{cardElement.icon}}">
  <a role="button" class="card btn" [href]="'#'+cardElement.id">
    <div class="card-body">
      <img class="row-box-icon"
           src="../../../assets/fonts/icons/{{cardElement.icon}}.svg"
           alt="Icon not found"/>
      <h4 class="bold card-title text-align-center">
        {{cardElement.title | translate}}<span class="bi-chevron-right bold"></span>
      </h4>
      <p class="card-text text-align-center py-2" [innerHtml]="cardElement.text | translate"></p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

*card-component.css*

```css
/* classes */
.row-box-icon {
  width: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.card, .card:hover {
  height: 100% !important;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: rgba(14, 44, 103, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.card-box-schaddow {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.card-title {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
```

chrome, firefox, edge:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnW7V.jpg)

safari:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NDGS.png)

I tried:

```css
.card, .card:hover {
  height: 100% !important;
  // ...
}
```

```css
.card, .card:hover {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  // ...
}
```

```css
.card, .card:hover {
  height: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  // ...
}
```

etc. but i cannot find the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer! it's

*home-page.css*

```css
app-card-content {
  display: grid !important;
}
```

safari
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmz7Q.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For your solution try to read that explanation on stackoverflow.

[Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636796/chrome-safari-not-filling-100-height-of-flex-parent)

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment